# Unselect the select all checkbox when one of the other checkboxes is unselected

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I iterate through an array to create some checkboxes, like below:

```
<div class="funnels">
    <label class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" id="selectall"> onClick="selectAll(this)" />All funnels
    </label>
    <?php foreach ($funnels as $funnel) { ?>
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" name="funnel[]" id ="funnel" value="<?php echo $funnel ?>" ><?php echo $funnel ?>
        </label>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I use the following javascript to select all checkboxes when the All checkbox has been clicked. What I need to do is to unselect the all checkbox once one of the other checkboxes has been unchecked.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
  function selectAll(source) {
         checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('funnel[]'); 
                for(i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` should be unique; so consider using class instead of id.

```
function selectAll(source) {
         checkboxes = document.querySelector('funnel[]'); 
                for(i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
    }
```

```js
function selectAll(source) {

  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.funnel'); 

  for(i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++)
     checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
    
function unSelect(element) {
if(!element.checked){
// uncheck "select all" when 1,2 or 3 is unchecked
  document.querySelector('#selectall').checked = false;
  // if you want to unselect also the others checkboxes of the class "funnel",uncomment the following block
  /*var others = document.querySelectorAll('.funnel'); 

  for(i=0;i<others.length;i++)
     others[i].checked = false;*/
  
}else{
// check "select all" when 1, 2, 3 is checked
  document.querySelector('#selectall').checked = true;
}
  
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" onclick="selectAll(this)" id="selectall"/> all select <br>

<input type="checkbox" class = "funnel" onclick="unSelect(this)"/> 1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" class = "funnel" onclick="unSelect(this)"/> 2 <br>
<input type="checkbox" class = "funnel" onclick="unSelect(this)"/> 3 <br>
```

Comment: Thank you again, the problem with this code would be that, when let's say we have four checkboxes, select all, 1,2,3 . By default it's set that the select all is selected. When I uncheck 1, then select all will become unchecked, but what if I check one again, then select all will still remain unchecked...

Comment: Do you want to check "select all" when 1 or 2 or 3 is checked?

Comment: I need the select all to be selected when 1,2,3 are selected. But then, if I uncheck 3, select all should be unchecked, and then if I check 3 again, select all should be checked aswell...

Comment: Thank you very much, this was perfect :):)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to bind `change` event handler to other `checkbox` element's also.

I would also recommend you to use unobtrusive event handlers see [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('funnel[]'),
    selectall = document.getElementById('selectall');


  for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
      //Conver to array
      var inputList = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkboxes);

      //Set checked  property of selectall input
      selectall.checked = inputList.every(function(c) {
        return c.checked;
      });
    });
  }


  selectall.addEventListener('change', function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
      checkboxes[i].checked = selectall.checked;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<label> <input type="checkbox" id="selectall"  />All funnels</label>
<br><label> <input type="checkbox" name="funnel[]" value="1">1</label>
<br><label> <input type="checkbox" name="funnel[]" value="2">2</label>
<br><label> <input type="checkbox" name="funnel[]" value="2">3</label>
```

Refrences

1. [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)
2. [Array.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)